# Insert At the beginning of Linked List

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

```
class Node:
def __init__(self,data):
    self.data=data
    self.next=None

head=Node(10)
head.next=Node(20)
head.next.next=Node(30)
head.next.next.next=Node(40)
head.next.next.next.next=Node(50)

def insertAtBegnning(head,x):
    temp=Node(100)
    temp.next=head
    return temp
head =insertAtBegnning(head,90)
```

1.In the above function i am able to add new node at the beginning but i tired it another way as below where i am not able to add new node at the beginning of a linked list.

```
def insertAtBegning(head,x):
    temp=head
    head=Node(x)
    head.next=temp
    return head

insertAtBegning(head,100)

def displayLinkedList(head):
    curr=head
    while(curr!=None):
       print (curr.data)
       curr=curr.next

displayLinkedList(head)
```

result: I am getting 10,20,30,40,50 but where i should get 100,10,20,30,40,50

2.can any one tell me  where i am going wrong in the above function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the value of `head` when you return it:

```
def insertAtBegning(head,x):
    temp=head
    head=Node(x)
    head.next=temp
    return head

# update 'head' here
head = insertAtBegning(head,100)

def displayLinkedList(head):
   curr=head
   while(curr!=None):
       print (curr.data)
       curr=curr.next

displayLinkedList(head)
```

Comment: why we  need to update as head= insertAtBegning(head,100) can you explain me bit on this

Comment: You create a new head node (different than your `head` outside, you re-bind it to a new value) inside your function at `head=Node(x)` which is not visible outside the function, so you need to return it and store in your `head` variable outside. @BASAVARAJJM